# What is the fastest way to cook a Meat Salad?

Tags: meat, microwave, salad

Meat salad is made with large sized sausages, chopped into thin pieces like carrots or cucumber; then steamed and fried a bit, then served together with regular salad stuffs.

Looking to specific alternatives, what is the fastest way to cook a Meat Salad (Beef/Buff) using a Microwave Oven? I have grill, convection and microwave modes in my Microwave Oven.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific - what kind of meat, for example.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall, I have updated the question.

Comment: I'm a little afraid to ask, but... what *is* a meat salad?

Comment: @Jefromi , to add additional emphasis, what **is** meat salad? (I presume based on involving a microwave we're not talking chicken or tuna salad here. Are you referring to Beef Masala? a la ["Beef cooked with onion, capsicum & tomato..."](http://www.thekathmanducottage.com/lunch.php) )

Comment: It's large sized sausages, chopped into thin pieces like carrots or cucumber and steam and fried and little, then served together with regular salad stuffs. I am little annoyed by the process of steaming and frying, so I though I could use my oven for that propose, but I dont know the right settings, so I asked. I TRIED MY BEST TO CLARIFY

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot speak to the benefits of the convection or grill modes of your microwave, I would use the main setting.

In the context of a salad setting, although you want moist meat, sausage would produce a bit much grease. If the grill setting can actually cauterize the meat without creating too much grease, or if you can capture the runoff (i.e. [with a bacon microwaving plate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JZ3UE4)), it would be more beneficial. In many cases, though, the microwave will soften the sausage, then cause it to dry out (again, you will want to capture the grease for the sake of the salad). Nonetheless, it seems like the microwave is a poor alternative, and (if it is smoked/pre-cooked sausage) you might better to just eat it cold.

That said, if the problem is that you are just looking for an alternative to steaming and then frying, have you consider braising, searing, grilling (if possible)? You could also do a marinade to moisten the meat and then do a quick, very high-temp fry (in a skillet) to just crust the marinade and heat the meat. These all seem faster or simpler than steaming and frying.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use a microwave to heat up that salat? Normally a meat salat isn't cooked/grilled or put into a microwave. The saucages you use are generally already pre-boiled and the salad is eaten cold.

Comment: This is not a answer, better keep this as a comment. And, I dont mean to cook, the entire salad in the oven, just the meat salad.